# SubOrchestartor and Activity functions - how do they differ in terms of execution & performance

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have the following codes 1) using SubOrchestratorFunction 2) using ActivityFunction:

```
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var j in js)
                {
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", j);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
```

```
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var j in js)
                {
                    var processTask = context.CallActivityAsync("ActivityFunction", j);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);               
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
```

How do these both differ in terms of execution and performance?

Answer (score 0):

A [Sub Orchestrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp) is exactly like a regular Orchestrator function and has the same [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints), i.e., can only have deterministic code and runs on a single thread.

The main use case for sub orchestrators is that you can split a large orchestration function into smaller units, which is [required for large fan-out scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#performance-targets).

If the code is the exact same (all constraints considered), then the execution and performance should be the same as well.

But the real benefits arise when you have complex and intensive code in your activity function (which can't be in an orchestrator function).